# Threading params in f#

Tags: f#

I have the following issue - a handful of functions and 2 types where each of the functions takes at least 2 params (one of each defined type).
Now those types are parametrized and can only be used with those functions if their generic type params fit.

```
type Record<'a, 'b> = { first: 'a; second: 'b }
type Lens<'a, 'b> = Lens of 'a * 'b

let someFn lens rec : Record<'a, 'b> = ....
let anotherFn lens rec : Record<'a, 'b> = ...
let aThirdFn lens rec : Record<'a, 'b> = ...
//and potentially a dozen functions more that might or might not return a record
```

The usage scenario is something like this

```
let workflow1 () = 
    let intIntLens = Lens (1, 1)
    let intIntRec = { first = 10; second = 100}

    intIntRec
    |> someFn intIntLens
    |> anotherFn intIntLens
    |> aThirdFn intIntLens

let workflow2 () = 
    let strIntLens = Lens ("foo", 1)
    let strIntRec = { first = "bar"; second = 100}

    strIntRec
    |> someFn strIntLens
    |> someFn strIntLens
    |> aThirdFn strIntLens
    |> anotherFn strIntLens
    |> someFn strIntLens
```

Now for any given workflow the lens type stays the same but record is being somehow processed.
However I have to thread the lens into each of those functions which is somehow boring.
One obvious option would be to have a mutable module level variable. Which I assume wouldnt work for much long in the face of concurrent code.

So what is the best approach to get rid of the lens param here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions always take and return the same type (meaning they themselves are all of the same type), you could just make a list of them and apply in order:

```
let ap lens fns rec = Seq.fold (fun r f -> f lens r) rec fns

let workflow2 () = 
    let strIntLens = Lens ("foo", 1)
    let strIntRec = { first = "bar"; second = 100}

    ap strIntLens [someFn; someFn; aThirdFn; anotherFn; someFn] strIntRec
```

I can't see how the functions could be of different types, but perhaps this is just a toy example, and your real problem actually does deal with functions of different types.
If that is the case, here's a slightly less elegant solution: define a pipe locally to close the lens within it.

```
let workflow2 () = 
    let strIntLens = Lens ("foo", 1)
    let strIntRec = { first = "bar"; second = 100}
    let (|*>) r f = f strIntLens r

    strIntLens 
    |*> someFn
    |*> someFn
    |*> aThirdFn
    |*> anotherFn
    |*> someFn
```

(Note that I did not reuse the standard pipe name `|>`. Though technically possible, that would make the code less readable)

Finally, you could go all-out on the problem, and combine input with lens in a single data structure, then create a custom pipe to work with such structure, which will apply the function, but tunnel the lens:

```
type RecAndLens<'a, 'b> = { rec: Record<'a, 'b>; lens: Lens<'a, 'b> }
let (|*>) rl f = { rec = f rl.lens rl.rec; lens = rl.lens }

let workflow2 () = 
    ...    
    { rec = strIntRec; lens = strIntLens }
    |*> someFn 
    |*> someFn 
    |*> aThirdFn 
    |*> anotherFn
    |*> someFn
```

This final approach would be a "long-term" kind of foundation, in case you're building a highly reusable library or something.

Technically, for a quick-and-dirty proof of concept, you could just use a tuple instead of the `RecAndLens` record:

```
let (|*>) (rec,lens) f = f lens rec, lens

let workflow2 () = 
    ...
    (strIntRec, strIntLens)
    |*> someFn 
    |*> someFn 
    |*> aThirdFn 
    |*> anotherFn
    |*> someFn
```

But this would be less sound, more error-prone (smells a bit of primitive obsession).